# Como centralizar horizontalmente uma div responsiva com vários objetos dentro

Tags: css

Eu gostaria de colocar o máximo de `Rectangle` possível dentro do `mainDiv`, e depois centralizar a `mainDiv` horizontalmente.
Por exemplo, nessa imagem podemos ver oito `Rectangle` dentro da `mainDiv`, porem tem um espaço no lado direito, eu gostaria de centralizar a `mainDiv`, para deixar a mesma margem do lado direito e do lado esquerdo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<div id="mainDiv" >
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #4d5f8d; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: explique melhor isso

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Já coloquei na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso?

```css
.Rectangle {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
  background: #4d5f8d; 
  margin-left: 20px; 
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  }
  .mainDiv {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv" >
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
    <div class="Rectangle" ></div>
</div>
```

ao chegar no limite do resize o elemento passa para baixo, mantendo assim os elemento centralizados